# data is display when page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to update throgh jquery i try this

```
 success:function(result)
        {
            alert("15-1");
            var up = JSON.parse(result.d).response;
            $("#txt_repeat" + obj.frequency).html(obj.frequency);
       $("#dura_values").find("option:contains(" + obj.Freq_Du + ")");

            debugger;
      $('#services_schdulue table > tbody:first').find('tr:first').html(result);

        },
```

There is a table. When i click on a row, pop up appears as a textbox which has the row data filled in. If I change data in the textbox and click save,**I want to show a confirmation message as " data is successfully saved".**

And secondly I want the **changed data to appear** in the row as soon as I click save **without any page refresh**. Current scenario is when i refresh page, updated data is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Just `$.load()` new data to your view:

```
$('.div-to-update').load(window.location.href+' .div-to-update > *', callbackFunction);
```

Comment: where i place this ? in success?

Comment: @greenuser `i want when i close pop up then updated data`... When you close popup, in close modal event

Comment: no i mean , i am done with close pop up.. there is close button when i click then pop is already close.. i want when i click on save button then want to update data.. data is already updated but this display when refreshing page..

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called "two way data binding". There is no simple aproach for that, even more as we do not know your application. There are frameworks which can help you, but for some of them the learning curve is rather steep.

http://jquerymy.com/

https://angularjs.org/

Comment: i am not familiar with these @Gerfried